# AngularJS - can I skip an interceptor?

Tags: angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

I have an AngularJS application with an interceptor to display error messages.

Sometimes the error message from the backend needs some front-end treatment to give more context, like changing a "access denied" into "You can't do this because of X".

How can I do this so the interceptor does not get called?

Right now I am endind up with 2 messages. The message from my controller and the message from the interceptor.

Comment: Who should decide when (not) to display a message from the interceptor? Based on what?

Comment: Based on the error response already being treated on the controller I believe.

Comment: It's not already treated. The interceptor is called *before* the controller gets the response. The controller could tell the interceptor which kinds of errors it *will* handle, though.

Comment: Is there another Angular structure to address this issue? Maybe something like the interceptor but *after* the request goes to the service? I am guessing this user case is bad.

Comment: My suggestion is that the controller should tell the interceptor what not to handle, when sending the request, by adding that information in the config object.

Comment: How would that work? I am looking at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage and I don't see where I could put something like that. Or is it possibel to put any arbitrary key that it will show up at the interceptor?

Comment: Yes, you can put whatever you want in config. It's a JavaScript object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163213/discussion-between-saita-and-jb-nizet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

service.js:

```
 myFunction: function(id) {
     return $http.post('myUrl/', {}, {skipErrorInterceptor: true});
 }
```

interceptor.js:

```
'responseError': function(rejection) {
    if (rejection.config.skipErrorInterceptor) {
         return $q.reject(rejection);
    } else {
        ... Global message treatment
    }
    return $q.reject(rejection);
 }
```